# Error when pull or push to git: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I have a problem every time I want to do pull or push from my GitHub repo using vscode git throw error message:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, watch 'c:\repos\app-repo\.git\refs\remotes\origin\master'
```

The repo is private in GitHub.
In `c:\repos\app-repo\.git\refs\remotes\origin` I have one file called HEAD.

What I should do? why this error happened?

Here the full error from the vscode-git-output-control:

```
git pull --tags origin master
> git show :package.json
From https://github.com/user/app-repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
> git rev-list --left-right master...refs/remotes/origin/master
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
Failed to watch ref 'c:\repos\app-repo\.git\refs\remotes\origin\master', is most likely packed.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, watch 'c:\repos\app-repo\.git\refs\remotes\origin\master'
    at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:164:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1232:11)
    at Object.t.watch (c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\main.js:1:6950)
    at E.updateTransientWatchers (c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\main.js:1:97463)
    at u.fire (c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:50:227)
    at T.updateModelState (c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\main.js:1:114843)
> git show :package.json
> git fetch
> git show :package.json
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git rev-parse master
> git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
> git rev-list --left-right master...refs/remotes/origin/master
> git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
> git remote --verbose
Failed to watch ref 'c:\repos\app-repo\.git\refs\remotes\origin\master', is most likely packed.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, watch 'c:\repos\app-repo\.git\refs\remotes\origin\master'
    at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:164:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1232:11)
    at Object.t.watch (c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\main.js:1:6950)
    at E.updateTransientWatchers (c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\main.js:1:97463)
    at u.fire (c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:50:227)
    at T.updateModelState (c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\resources\app\extensions\git\dist\main.js:1:114843)
> git show :package.json
```

Comment: Do you have a master branch in your repo on github?

Comment: yes. I have. it point to master branch.

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio so I may be talking through my hat, but: this looks like a bug (or bug-ette) in VS. Packed refs are normal. If VS wants to know about a ref change and the ref doesn't exist, it should do a file-system-watch on the containing directory, or just keep retrying the ref without complaining. Whether this bug will interfere with you getting your own work done, I don't know.

Comment: FWIW, I'm getting this too. I'm seeing it in VS code output pane after cloning a fresh copy of a repo and opening that dir as a new workspace.

Answer (score 18):

I solved this creating the branch folder, in my case:

```
mkdir /home/projects/project_example/.git/refs/remotes/origin/branch_name
```

Comment: Verified as of Feb-2024, VSCode v1.85.2. New repo, got warning on trying to commit new content. Stashed content, created branch, pushed branch, no issue. Apply stash and commit. No more ENOENT warning.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem while trying to push to GitHub's private repo through VS Code on Mac (SSH with passphrase). Somehow it worked after creating a branch as posted by ZiTAL. It's weird though.

Comment: this happened to me on vs code as well, it would appear to be a somewhat common issue as i've seen a few threads on git about it with raised issues and no solution.